# Using stage.addEventListener inside a class is returning a null object reference during runtime

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, oop

I want to add an event listener to the stage from inside a class called "ChoiceBtn".

I get the error "1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference". I understand that this is because the object is not yet instantiated.

Here is my code:

My main document code:

```
    import ChoiceBtn;

var op1:ChoiceBtn = new ChoiceBtn("display meee", answer, 1, "a)", "4.jpg");
op1.x = 250;
op1.y = 60;
stage.addChild(op1);
```

My Class file:

```
package  {

import AnswerEvent;
import flash.display.Loader;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.display.SimpleButton;
import flash.events.*;
import flash.ui.Mouse;
import flash.text.TextField;
import flash.text.TextFormat;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.display.Stage;

public class ChoiceBtn extends Sprite{
    public var path:String;
    public var choiceText:String;
    public var choiceLabel:String;

    private var answer:Answer;
    private var choiceNum:uint;
    private var textFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
    private var choiceLabelHwd:TextField = new TextField();
    private var choiceTextHwd:TextField = new TextField();
    private var boundingRect:Sprite = new Sprite;
    private var hitAreaWidth = 255;
    private var hitAreaHeight = 45;
    private var pic:Loader = new Loader;

    public function ChoiceBtn(choiceText:String, answer:Answer, choiceNum:uint, choiceLabel:String = "a)", picPath:String = null) {
        //path - must be the path to a picture
        //choiceText - the text to be displayed
        //choiceLabel - the prefix selector such as answers '1' or 'a)' etc.

        // constructor code
        this.answer = answer;
        this.choiceNum = choiceNum;
        this.choiceLabel = choiceLabel;
        this.choiceText = choiceText;

        //add childs
        addChild(this.choiceTextHwd);
        addChild(this.choiceLabelHwd);
        addChild(this.boundingRect);    //must be added last so is on top of everything else

        //add Listeners
        //stage.addEventListener(AnswerEvent.EVENT_ANSWERED, update); //doesn't work
        stage.addEventListener(AnswerEvent.EVENT_ANSWERED, this.update); //doesn't work either
    }

    public function update(e:Event):void {
        trace("in choice fired");
    }
}
}
```

I don't understand why it doesn't work even when I use `this` before the function. How can I create the eventlistener on the stage in this classes constructor code and reference a function inside this class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wait for the ADDED_TO_STAGE event to fire first:

```
public function ChoiceButton():void
{
    // your code.. etc..    
    addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE,addListeners);
}

private function addListeners(event:Event):void
{
    stage.addEventListener(AnswerEvent.EVENT_ANSWERED, update);             
}
```

Comment: Just to expand a bit on Nuthman's answer, you cannot access the stage property of a display object until after that object has been added to the stage.

Comment: This fixes everything perfectly. Thank you :).

Comment: I just realized that I accidentally added the event listener twice. I fixed it :)